# Parsing JSON of a particular case

Tags: java, json

I am trying retrieving the following JSON data from imagga's image recognition API.

```
{"results":[{"image":"http://docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg","tagging_id":null,"tags":[{"confidence":63.346307851163395,"tag":"valley"},{"confidence":60.66263009377379,"tag":"mountain"},{"confidence":44.39096006516168,"tag":"canyon"},{"confidence":42.08210930346856,"tag":"landscape"},{"confidence":33.52198895357515,"tag":"geological formation"},{"confidence":32.702112467737216,"tag":"mountains"},{"confidence":28.626223994488203,"tag":"glacier"},{"confidence":28.36,"tag":"natural depression"},{"confidence":28.03481906795487,"tag":"ravine"},{"confidence":27.269738461024804,"tag":"sky"},{"confidence":26.130797131953397,"tag":"rock"},{"confidence":23.11898739400327,"tag":"travel"},{"confidence":21.75182989551758,"tag":"alp"},{"confidence":20.956625061326214,"tag":"national"},{"confidence":20.15360199670358,"tag":"park"},{"confidence":19.826365024393702,"tag":"stone"},{"confidence":19.717420656127437,"tag":"water"},{"confidence":18.049071926896588,"tag":"river"},{"confidence":17.81629840041474,"tag":"hill"},{"confidence":17.30594970410163,"tag":"tourism"},{"confidence":17.192663177192692,"tag":"clouds"},{"confidence":16.53588724897844,"tag":"scenic"},{"confidence":15.98967256769248,"tag":"peak"},{"confidence":15.792599629554461,"tag":"lake"},{"confidence":15.532788988165363,"tag":"scenery"},{"confidence":15.453814687301834,"tag":"snow"},{"confidence":15.232632664896412,"tag":"outdoors"},{"confidence":15.212304004139495,"tag":"range"},{"confidence":15.042325772263556,"tag":"hiking"},{"confidence":14.958759294889424,"tag":"tree"},{"confidence":14.78842712696222,"tag":"forest"},{"confidence":12.853490785491731,"tag":"grass"},{"confidence":12.242518977753525,"tag":"desert"},{"confidence":12.095999999999998,"tag":"natural elevation"},{"confidence":12.03899501602295,"tag":"america"},{"confidence":11.49381779097963,"tag":"environment"},{"confidence":11.250534926394025,"tag":"usa"},{"confidence":10.935999552280517,"tag":"panorama"},{"confidence":10.838870815021957,"tag":"trees"},{"confidence":10.77081532273937,"tag":"south"},{"confidence":10.385222667460749,"tag":"summer"},{"confidence":9.967993711501377,"tag":"cloud"},{"confidence":9.960797892906747,"tag":"wild"},{"confidence":9.840206836878211,"tag":"natural"},{"confidence":9.64736797817423,"tag":"geology"},{"confidence":9.622992778171428,"tag":"rocky"},{"confidence":9.5011692563878,"tag":"outdoor"},{"confidence":9.36921935993258,"tag":"wilderness"},{"confidence":9.360136841263397,"tag":"vacation"},{"confidence":9.295849004816608,"tag":"rocks"},{"confidence":9.200756690906687,"tag":"high"},{"confidence":9.098263071652019,"tag":"highland"},{"confidence":8.912795414022,"tag":"tourist"},{"confidence":8.871604649828521,"tag":"hike"},{"confidence":8.849249986309006,"tag":"landmark"},{"confidence":8.696713373486205,"tag":"cliff"},{"confidence":8.600291951670297,"tag":"scene"},{"confidence":8.535889495009538,"tag":"stream"},{"confidence":8.530021520404471,"tag":"sunny"},{"confidence":8.255077489679804,"tag":"altitude"},{"confidence":8.016191292928964,"tag":"trail"},{"confidence":7.9938748285500605,"tag":"autumn"},{"confidence":7.985278417869093,"tag":"california"},{"confidence":7.927492176055299,"tag":"spain"},{"confidence":7.774043777890904,"tag":"adventure"},{"confidence":7.560207874392119,"tag":"peaceful"},{"confidence":7.485827508554503,"tag":"fall"},{"confidence":7.283862421876644,"tag":"erosion"},{"confidence":7.272123549182718,"tag":"terrain"},{"confidence":7.24510515635207,"tag":"rural"},{"confidence":7.234934522337296,"tag":"vista"},{"confidence":7.092282542389207,"tag":"holiday"}]}]}
```

I am using http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgjson20130603jar.htm library.

My Java code is as follows:

```
String imageUrl = "http://docs.imagga.com/static/images/docs/sample/japan-605234_1280.jpg",
                            apiKey = "",
                            apiSecret = "";

                            // These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/java

                            HttpResponse response = Unirest.get("https://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging")
                                    .queryString("url", imageUrl)
                                    .basicAuth(apiKey, apiSecret)
                                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                    .asJson();


            String js = response.getBody().toString();
                        System.out.println(js.toString());


                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody()); // json
                        System.out.print("hello");
                        JSONObject data1 = jObject.getJSONObject("results"); // get data
                        System.out.print(data1);                                            // object
                        String projectname = data1.getString("tags"); // get the name
                                                                        // from data.
                        System.out.print(projectname);
```

I am getting the error that

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException:
>   JSONObject["results"] not found.

What I want to get is the list of "tag" and "confidence".

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to expose apiKey and apiSecret to the public...

Comment: Just edited it out. Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Check carefully "results" is not json object it is json array

Comment: @Vickyexpert I think so too.  try **getJSONArray()**.

Comment: @starry You should change your API-KEY and SECRET *IMMEDIATELY* since it will still be visibile in the revisions of your post!

Comment: @questionare: i cant seem to remove it from the revision history :/

Comment: @starry No, but you could change it in your service you are using.

Comment: @questionare: Thats done. My bad !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   JSONArray data1 = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
```

**Edited Answer**

```
    String js = response.getBody().toString();
    System.out.println(js.toString());


    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(js); // json
    System.out.print("hello");
    JSONArray data1 = jObject.getJSONArray("results");

    for(int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = data1.getJSONObject(i);
        String projectn ame = jsonObject.getString("tagging_id");                                                                       
        System.out.print(projectname);

        JSONArray tagArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("tags");

        for(int j = 0; j < tagArray.length; j++)
        {
             JSONObject tagObject = tagArray.getJSON(j);
             System.out.println("Tag == " + tagObject.getString("tag"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Still seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["results"] not found.

Comment: 'JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(response.getBody()); // json
      JSONArray data1 = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
      
           
      String projectname = data1.getString("tags"); // get the name
                  // from data.
      System.out.print(projectname);'

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the list of tag and confidence.

Comment: Still same error : Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["results"] not found.

Comment: did you get the response or it is null ?

Comment: I am getting the response as shown in the OP in the console. Then the error shows up in the console when I tried JSONArray using your code.

Comment: use js instead of response.getBody(), check my edited answer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["tags"] not a string. Still this error. It doesnt seem to parse it correctly. Been trying your code and variations of it.

Comment: Check again your error as you have resolved the error of first array object now you have to manage other objects as well, you are getting error in tags because it is also not an JSONObject, it is JSONArray so you have to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should try `jObject.getJSONArray("results")` instead of `jObject.getJSONObject("results")`.

There is also a good tool to convert json to java: http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/

If you use it, you will see:

```
    ...other code...

    public class RootObject
    {
      private ArrayList<Result> results;

      public ArrayList<Result> getResults() { return this.results; }

      public void setResults(ArrayList<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
    }

...other code...
```

And `results` is list here, so use `getJSONArray` instead of `getJSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

To make your life more easy I'd go to model the Objects as POJO's and let Jackson's Objectmapper do the magic.

See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your json `results` has an array in it and therefore you should use `getJSONArray` and not `getJSONObject`.

```
JSONArray data1 = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
```